# Matlab error with 2D Fourier transform of images

Tags: matlab, 2d, fft

I have written a program implementing the fft2 command to get the Fourier transformation of an image along with other changes and i keep recieving an out put error for:
Error in fft2 (line 17)
F=fft2(imdata);
Below is my code for this program. I also wrote the program another way and had the same error fo the same function.

```
close all; clc
imdata = imread('BluOrn Star.jpg');
figure(1);
imshow(imdata); 
originalRGBImage = imdata; % Save original image for later display in figure (7)
title('Original Image');
imdata = rgb2gray(imdata);
figure(2); 
imshow(imdata); 
title('Gray Image');
%Get Fourier Transform of an image
F = fft2(imdata);
% Fourier transform of an image
S = abs(F);
figure(3);
imshow(S,[]);
title('Fourier transform of an image');
%get the centered spectrum
Fsh = fftshift(F);
figure(4);imshow(abs(Fsh),[]);
title('Centered fourier transform of Image')
%apply log transform
S2 = log(1+abs(Fsh));
figure(5);imshow(S2,[]);
title('log transformed Image')
%reconstruct the Image
F = ifftshift(Fsh);
f = ifft2(F);
figure(6);imshow(f,[]),
title('reconstructed Image')
h7 = figure(7);
imshow(originalRGBImage);
```

error code:

```
Attempt to execute SCRIPT fft2 as a function:
/MATLAB Drive/fft2.m
Error in FFT2Image (line 13)
F = fft2(imdata); 
>>
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the full error message. MATLAB has very informative error messages, paraphrasing them is not helpful.

Comment: did you name your function (or any other function) you made fft2 by any chance? It seems MATLAB is finding another fft2 script not the in-built fft2 function.

Comment: Rename the script `/MATLAB Drive/fft2.m` to something else. You should never name scripts or functions the same as built-in functions, as they shadow (=hide) those functions.

Comment: Thank you that was it I mistakenly had named the other progra i made fft2.m.